# getting list elements from a redis server ,from []interface{} to []string

Tags: types, redis, go

I trying to connect [redis](/questions/tagged/redis) with [go](/questions/tagged/go) using [redigo](https://github.com/garyburd/redigo), `redis-server` is running.

I want to create a [list](http://redis.io/commands#list) of strings, append one string , then get all the elements from the server and print them out.

this , what I tried

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis"
)

func main() {
    c, err := redis.Dial("tcp", ":6379")
    check(err)
    defer c.Close()
    _, err = c.Do("LPUSH", "bars", "foo")
    check(err)

    n, err := redis.Values(c.Do("LRANGE", "bars", 0, 10))
    check(err)
    fmt.Println(n)
}

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

I get  `[[102 111 111]]` printed instead of `foo`, it seems that

How can I convert `[]interface{}` ([Values](http://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#Values)  return type) to `[]string` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the package you're using, but [the documentation](http://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#Strings) suggests that using `redis.Strings()` instead of `redis.Values()` will do what you're after:

> Strings is a helper that converts a multi-bulk command reply to a []string. If err is not equal to nil, then Strings returns nil, err. If one if the multi-bulk items is not a bulk value or nil, then Strings returns an error.

Answer (score -2):

maybe you can try this redis client for golang:

https://github.com/xuyu/goredis

:)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.